# How to extract JSON fields from an api

Tags: java, json, api, rest, jax-rs

I have an api which returns data in the below format when i use the clientbuilder get():

```
final Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("url").queryParam("CustomerQuery", jsonarr).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
String actual = response.readEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(actual);
```

Result:

```
{"_id":{"timestamp":1649320244,"date":"2022-04-07T08:30:44.000+00:00"},"ScheduleTime":"2022-04-07T09:50:00.000+00:00","History":[{"Status":"Pending","Time":"2022-04-07T08:30:44.011+00:00"}],"MyDetails":{"Query":"query1^^","name":"NEH","address":"XXX","Format":"xml","Version":"2"}}
{"_id":{"timestamp":1649320255,"date":"2022-04-07T08:30:55.000+00:00"},"ScheduleTime":"2022-04-07T09:50:00.000+00:00","History":[{"Status":"Pending","Time":"2022-04-07T08:30:55.011+00:00"}],"MyDetails":{"Query":"query2^^^","name":"ABC","address":"YYY","Format":"xml","Version":"1"}}
```

I need to extract fields under MyDetails in the above string and i tried using :

```
final Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("url").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
    JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.readEntity(String.class)));
    System.out.println(jsonReader.readObject());
```

Please let me know how can i extract the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have questions about how to use a JsonObject, read the Javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.readEntity(String.class)));
JsonObject o = jsonReader.readObject();
JsonObject details = o.getJsonObject("MyDetails");

// details.get...
```

Alternatively, use a different http client like Retrofit that encourages direct object mapping

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do what you want to do. I will just describe some of them. You can use several Json parsing libraries. The most popular ones are Json-Jackson also known as faster XML ([See link here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)). You can use method [readValue](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)) of ObjectMapper class. For class parameter you can use Map.class or your custom written class that will reflect the structure of your Json.

Than there is [Gson library](https://github.com/google/gson), with its [user guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)

But also if you want a simplistic solution, I wrote my own open-source library that includes JsonUtils class that is a thin wrapper over Json-Jackson library that gives you a very simple solution. In your case it may look like this (assuming variable `json` is a `String` that contains your Json string):

```
try {
  Map<String, Object>map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(json, Map.class);
  Map details = map.get("MyDetails");
} catch(IOException ioe) {
...
}
```

Map `details` will contain a map with all your keys and values from section "MyDetails". If you want to use this library here is where to get it: Its called MgntUtils and you can get it on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) with Javadoc and source code. It is available as [maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.github.michaelgantman%20AND%20a:MgntUtils) as well. Here is a Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class

Comment: Jackson can already read strings to Map objects, so why is your utility needed?

Comment: I mentioned Jackson as the first option. My utility simplifies things for many cases. So OP can use jackson or my utility. For example for Jackson you need to include 2 dependencies - minimum and sometimes 3. My utility wraps it up all in one and provides very simplified methods that actually cover majority of the cases. So if your use cases are simple use of my utility makes it simpler code and code mantanance